# Questions about this bit of Java code, why it is written as it is

Tags: java, set, bitwise-or

I came across this source code and wanted to make sure I understood why it is written as it is ( or if it should be ):

```
boolean modified = false;
Set<String> possibleSites = settings.getPossibleSites();
Set<String> visibleSites = settings.getVisibleSites();
modified = someMysteriousMethod();

// Remove sites from visibleSites that are not in possibleSites
modified |= visibleSites.retainAll(possibleSites);
```

My questions about the LAST statement:

1. Why use the bitwise operator?  retainAll() will return a boolean as to what happened?
2. What is the operator/statement saying? If modified equals the return value leave the value of modified alone OR if the return value is different set modified to that new value?

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation of [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c)
```

returns `true` if `the set changed as a result of the call`

```
modified |= visibleSites.retainAll(possibleSites);
```

So the above statement means, if `modified` is **true** OR `retainAll` returns **true**, then `modified` is set to **true**, otherwise the value of `modified` is **false**

Answer (score 1):

It is meant to say that if either `modified` or `retainAll()` is true, then `modified` should be true. (Which makes sense given the name. `retainAll` only returns true if the `Set` was changed, and `someMysteriousMethod` probably returns true or false depending if the state of the `Set` was changed.)

The code breaks down to:

```
modified = modified | visibleSites.retainAll(possibleSites);
```

Look at the following code to see the results of the `|` on booleans:

```
System.out.println(true|true);
System.out.println(false|true);
System.out.println(true|false);
System.out.println(false|false);
```

Output:

```
true
true
true
false
```

(Only `false|false` will return `false`, so in the code, both `modified` and `retainAll` will have to return false for `modified` to be `false`)

Answer (score 0):

The return value of [`retainAll` method in `Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) indicates whether the set was changed by the call.

> Returns:
>
> `true` if this set changed as a result of the call

Here, `true` indicates that the set was modified.  The `|=` compound operator performs an "or" on the arguments and assigns it back to the left side.  With your case that means that if `retainAll` returns `true`, then assign `true` back to `modified`, or else leave `modified` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

According to the javadoc,

> `retainAll` retuns `true` if this set changed as a result of the call

`a |= b` is an operation that affects the result of "`a or b`" to `a`.
Therefore, in your situation, the idea is to affect to `modified` the result of the statement "`visibleSites` was modified before `OR` `visibleSites` was modified by `retainAll`"

Answer (score 0):

After this:

> modified = someMysteriousMethod();

then `modified` may be true, or not.  The *effect* of the following:

> modified |= visibleSites.retainAll(possibleSites);

is to leave `modified` set true if it was already true, and to change it from false to true if some other condition holds (I say *effect* intentionally, I am not describing actual instruction operation).

The second statement could be written as

```
if (visibleSites.retainAll(possibleSites)) {
      modified = true;
}
```

with the same outcome. To some extent this is a matter of taste. I find the original (using the `|=` operator) to be clearer to read, since it's a simple straight-line logical expression rather than a control-flow statement

By the way, it's not called a 'bitwise' operator.  Java has two '|' and two corresponding '|=' operators; between integers it's [bitwise-or](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1), between booleans it's [logical-or](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2).